# Update documents based on multiple dropdown values

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, semantic-ui, dropdown

I am building an administration panel within a meteor app to be able to manage the users of the app.  Currently I am displaying all the users with a dropdown for each user to change their role .

I need to update the changed roles **only after I hit** some confirmation button at the end.

I have a template that gets rendered with the username and a dropdown with the current role of the user, my template is similar to this:

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="role">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">{{role}}</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="admin">Admin</div>
    .
    .
    .
    <div class="item" data-value="user">User</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This renders as many as users I have in my database. I need to update **all** users who have their role changed after clicking a button.

My current approach is to plug the user id to the dropdown:

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown" id={{_id}}>
```

Then I have an event handler for the dropdown change and catch the value:

```
Template.templateName.events({
  "change .ui.selection.dropdown": function(event, template) {
    var id = template.find(".ui.selection.dropdown").id;
    var role = template.find("input[name=role]").value;
    ...
  },

});
```

Now I am wondering if I should  push those `id,role` pairs in some session key and update the users after clicking `save` button or there is a better and more effective alternatives for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving them in session variable and clearing session variable on template's `destroyed` callback, you can add an attribute to the changed element indicating that the element has changed. When save button is clicked, you can use [attribute selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) to get all the elements that were changed by this user. See the code sample below for further reference.

```
Template.templateName.events({
  "change .ui.selection.dropdown": function(event, template) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    target.attr("data-changed", "data-changed");
  },
  "click #saveButtonId": function(event, template) {
    var changedElements = template.$(".ui.selection.dropdown[data-changed]");
    var changedItems = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < changedElements.length; i++) {
       var changedElement = changedElements[i];
       changedItems.push({ id: changedElement.id, value: changedElement.value });
       // or
       //changedItems.push([changedElement.id, changedElement.value]);

    }
    // here you can call a meteor method like
    // Meteor.call('updateUserRoles', changedItems); //this updateUserRoles will now get only changed items that you can update in your DB.
  }
});
```